# how to remove first item from list and keep index

Tags: c#

I have a list and want to remove the first item while keeping the index of the next the same. For example:

```
public List<string> Fruit
{
    get
    {
        List<string> fruits = dataSource.GetFruits();

        return messageStatuses ;
    }
}
```

result returned

```
[0] -- apple
[1] -- grape
[2] -- orange
[3] -- peach
```

when the first item is remove the result should be:

```
[1] -- grape
[2] -- orange
[3] -- peach
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use a `Dictionary<Int32, String>` for this, and remove the key.

Comment: BTW: You really didn't include the relevant code that returns the results you showed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use dictionary for this

```
Dictionary<int,string> dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();

dic.Add(0,"Apple");
dic.Add(1,"Grape");
dic.Add(2,"Orange");
dic.Add(3,"Peach");

dic.Remove(0);
```

Now 
    `dic[1]` will give you `"Grape"`

Answer (score 2):

Just set the item at index 0 to `null`, or some other value to indicate that it was removed.  Obviously for value types (i.e. `int`) this may not be a feasible option.  It will also result in the `Count` including all of the null values, which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Work with an array instead of a list. This will allow for you to remove items at certain indexes, without messing up the indexing itself.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in C# don't function like a JavaScript array, where you can remove an item and leave `undefined` in it's place.

You need to replace your value with a placeholder you can ignore. Something like

```
Fruit[0] = "ignore";
```

and then deal with that in your loops.